Why does my Azure Trusted Signing GitHub Action fail with "Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed."
I've signed up for a Azure Trusted Signing account and created a validated identity and a certificate profile. I have registered an app in Azure Entra ID, and given this the role of Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer on the account.
I've also created a GitHub Action that downloads a file from Azure Blob Storage, and then attempts to sign it. But the signing process fails with the error Unhandled managed exception
Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed. Status: 403 (Forbidden).
And I can't see where my error is.
This is the GitHub action (it also check if the file is actually there):
jobs:
  download-and-sign:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    name: Download file and sign it
    steps:
      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
          
      - name: Download the file
        run: |
          Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/my-file.msi' -OutFile 'my-file.msi'

      - name: 'Check File Existence'
        id: check_files
        uses: andstor/file-existence-action@v3
        with:
          files: 'my-file.msi'

      - name: Files exist
        if: steps.check_files.outputs.exists == 'true'
        run: echo "All files exist!"

      - name: Sign files with Trusted Signing
        uses: azure/trusted-signing-action@v0.3.16
        with:
          azure-tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}
          azure-client-id: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}
          azure-client-secret: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET }}
          endpoint: https://eus.codesigning.azure.net/
          code-signing-account-name: my-code-signing-account
          certificate-profile-name: my-certificate-profile
          files-folder: ${{ github.workspace }}
          files-folder-recurse: true
          files-folder-filter: msi
          # files-catalog: ${{ github.workspace }}\my-file.msi
          file-digest: SHA256
          timestamp-rfc3161: http://timestamp.acs.microsoft.com
          timestamp-digest: SHA256
          exclude-interactive-browser-credential: false
          timeout: 1200

This is the output:
Invoke-TrustedSigning @params
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    DOTNET_ROOT: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\dotnet
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: ***
    AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ***
    AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: ***
    AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH: 
    AZURE_CLIENT_SEND_CERTIFICATE_CHAIN: 
    AZURE_USERNAME: 
    AZURE_PASSWORD: 
  
Azure Code Signing
Version: 1.0.52
"Metadata": {
  "Endpoint": "https://eus.codesigning.azure.net/",
  "CodeSigningAccountName": "my-code-signing-account",
  "CertificateProfileName": "my-certificate-profile",
  "ExcludeCredentials": []
}
Submitting digest for signing...
Unhandled managed exception
Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
Headers:
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2024 06:46:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
x-azure-ref: REDACTED
X-Cache: REDACTED
Content-Length: 0
   at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileRestClient.SignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.CertificateProfileClient.StartSignAsync(String codeSigningAccountName, String certificateProfileName, SignRequest body, String xCorrelationId, String clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.SignAsync(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.CodeSigning.Dlib.Core.DigestSigner.Sign(UInt32 algorithm, Byte[] digest, SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle)
   at AuthenticodeDigestSignExWithFileHandleManaged(_CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pMetadataBlob, UInt32 digestAlgId, Byte* pbToBeSignedDigest, UInt32 cbToBeSignedDigest, Void* hFile, _CRYPTOAPI_BLOB* pSignedDigest, _CERT_CONTEXT** ppSignerCert, Void* hCertChainStore)
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147467259/0x80004005)
Exception: SignTool failed with exit code 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET as secrets in my repo. These are the values of the app registered in Entra ID. The endpoint value is the same value as listed in my Trusted Signing account.
I can see that there is something with my access, but I can't see why. Any pointers are much appreciated.

Have you assigned Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal? If not, kindly assign the same role to service principal and run the pipeline again.

The downloaded file is a public file, and the "andstor/file-existence-action@v3" action confirms that it is downloaded. But I'm open to all suggestions, and has now given the principal the role Storage Blob Data Contributor on the storage account I'm downloading from. Still the same message, unfortunately.

Make sure to check the Trusted Signing Certificate Profile Signer role to correct service principal.

It would be ideal if you filed an issue on GitHub
https://github.com/azure/trusted-signing-action
That way the Trusted Signing product group can communicate with you and figure out what is going on.

For 403s there can be a few things that can cause this, please check/verify the below:

Check Trusted Signing role.
Check Trusted Signing account name and Trusted Signing Certificate profile name n your metadata.json.
Check dlib and dlib path
Install C++ Redistributables: Download link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
Check .Net version, dlib version and Windows SDK
Check if Trusted Signing role is assigned to the identity trying to sign the file.
Check if the corresponding Identity Validation is in "Completed" state.
Verify if you access to the Trusted Signing endpoint from the VM or machine you are trying to sign from? Try executing the action on a different VM or machine. It can be a potential network issue.


@amazeblase this is gold!! please send to MS for them to updated their docs
